# Downtime is on when in Settings it says it is off

Tags: iphone, ios, parental-controls, screen-time

Every week on Monday downtime turns on and I can't do anything outside the limitations my dad has set for me. Every time I get downtimed, I go into Settings>Screen Time and i see that downtime is actually off. Originally I thought htat the school's wifi was messing with things on my phone since they do block a lot iCloud services. I currently use a 2nd generation iPhone SE running the latest version of iOS.

Things I have tried one or more times:

- Rebooting
- Telling my dad to just shut off screen time entirely (obviously didn't work)
- Updating iOS (I updated to 16.4 a few days before this edit, didn'f fix anything)
- Turning off app limits (don't know what my dad's thinking was there but it didn't do anything)

Things that I have not tried yet:

- Reinstalling iOS
- Signing out and signing back in

One thing that has started happening recently is me getting a downtime notification at around 3pm saying "426 minutes remaining before downtime" or something. Then around 5 minutes later, downtime is on. Here is a screenshot of the notification:
[image: the notification]

This has been happening for a long time now, and we have only found one *temporary*
solution: Toggling downtime. My dad says he doesn't have any clue why this keeps happening so regularly, and he is the only one who can do anything about it. This same problem was happening to my late 2014 Mac mini.

Comment: It’s not clear the problem you’re experiencing.  Is your iPhone going into downtime during the time set by your father or is it happening outside the schedule?

Comment: @Allan both. when it happens outside of the schedule, it happens on the same day each week if i connect to my school's wifi. when i dont, that day will be set to the next time i connect. for example recently we had a week off of school because of midwinter break (monday and tuesday) and this big ice storm (wednesday and thursday) and when i was sick on friday

Comment: This type of thing is happening to my kid too. Specifically, when I turn Downtime off (so that my kid should be able to use apps), my kid’s phone’s settings does show Downtime as being off, but the phone still locks out access to apps.